# Bash Script - PHP script with Variables

Tags: php, bash

I can run a php file in Bash script but I can't run with variables

*Non-variables with Working:*

```
#!/bin/bash

data=$(/usr/bin/php -q /home/PATH/contest.php);
```

*Variables with Not Working:*

```
#!/bin/bash

data=$(/usr/bin/php -q /home/PATH/contest.php data=Nov14&day=3);
```

What is the reason of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved.

> *You can easily parse command line arguments into the $_GET variable by using the parse_str() function.*

I added my PHP script top

```
parse_str(implode('&', array_slice($argv, 1)), $_GET);
```

[PHP Documents](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php)